# ByteArray uncompress asynchronously

Tags: actionscript-3, air, compression, arrays

I need to uncompress huge compressed string (~ 40mb after uncomression), can't use concurrency, cause project is Mobile Air. 
Script is very simple, just:

```
byteArray.uncompress();
```

Uncompression takes time (more then ~5 sec on Sony Xperia Sola). Is there any way  to uncompress in async mode? So at least I'll make some spinner animations or something like that while operation.

One more question to this:
How to divide data in to chuncks, uncompress them and collect afterwards?

Comment: I don't believe there is an async equivalent, perhaps you could get better performance using an ANE (granted you would need one implementation for each platform/target architecture, but I imagine compression is something that there's native classes for regardless of platform).  Another option might be to compress/decompress the data in chunks, so instead of 1 40MB ByteArray make 10 4MB byte arrays and update a progress bar between each one loading.

Comment: You mean do something like this:
    var chunkBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    chunkBytes.writeBytes(compressedData,0,1024);
And uncompress chunkBytes incrementally?

Comment: Yup something like that.  Basically the solution to a single thread in Flash has generally been called "green threading" and involves breaking up the function calls into pieces, I'm just playing off that idea.

Comment: There's some info in the links at the bottom of this page on Green threads: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS948100b6829bd5a6-4c2e64612754b0a95b-8000.htm

Comment: Thanks, I'll try.
Additionally Alchemy came on mind, might be faster then AS3 (despite that I'm using byteArray), this would help with platform based ANEs too.

Comment: Just had another thought, I've been using some third party open source zip libraries for my own mobile project.  Despite having some delays as well they might be of interest to you http://nochump.com/blog/archives/15 or http://codeazur.com.br/lab/fzip/